# For which values of $a$ and $b$ is $T$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question:**

> For $a,b \in \mathbb R$, the transformation $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3 $ defined by $$T(x,y)=(2x-y,3x+y+3a,5x-2y+bxy)$$
> is linear if
>
> 1. $a=b=1$
> 2. $a=0, b=1$
> 3. $a=1,b=0$
> 4. None of the above

**My attempt:**

Let $k \in \mathbb R$, then consider $$T(k(x,y))=T(kx,ky)=\left( k(2x-y), k(3x+y)+3a,k(5x-2y+kbxy)\right)$$

Now firstly, looking at the second coordinate, we need to be able to factor out $k$ out of all terms, and the remaining terms inside of the bracket needs to equal the original $T$, to have that $T(k(x,y))=kT(x,y)$ in order for $T$ to be linear, and hence we need $$3a=3ak$$ for all choices of $k$. Now this is only true if and only if $a=0$.

Lastly, we need $$kbxy = bxy$$ for all choices of $k$, which is only true if $b=1$.

This is solution 2 of the multiple choice.
However, the memo says that (4. None of the above) is the correct answer.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you meant $b=1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Apologies yes, that was a typo. $b=1$. I have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b=1$, then that equality becomes $kxy=xy$. That surely doesn't hold for every $x$ and every $y$. The only $b$ that works is $b=0$.

Comment: Of course! That was very silly of me to miss. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a more simple way (maybe ?) to see that $a=0$ is to compute $T(0,0)$, which need to be equal to (0,0,0) by linearity. This can be a useful reflex when we want to show non-linearity or find conditions on the parameters. But of course your approach is the general one using the definition so it's totally good.

Secondly, the $xy$ term is clearly not linear in $x$ and $y$ (in fact, it's bilinear) so I would say we need $b=0$ intuitively. Following what you obtained, I don't see why you conclude you need b=1 ? If we take k=2 and b=1, then the expression become $2xy=xy$ which is false. It's b=0 that works.

Answer (score 1):

$T:V\to\Bbb{ R^n}$ given by

$T(v) =(f_1(v), f_2(v),..., f_n(v)) $$ \forall v\in V$

Then $T$ is linear if $f_i :V\to \Bbb{R}$ is linear. Hurry

Now, check when coordinate functional are linear.